# Select2 dropdown menu detaches in Cordova / Phonegap

Tags: jquery, css, cordova, jquery-select2, phonegap

I am using Select2 dropdown inside my Cordova / Phonegap app and it's working perfectly. Except when someone scrolls the background, the dropdown content detaches from the dropdown and it's resulting in a bad experience for the user.

Does anyone know how to fix that with CSS or jQuery?

I am initializing it normally like:

```
$(".search__box").select2({
              minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
              width: '100%'
});
```

And then the code is like this:

```
<script type="text/ons-template" id="home.html">
<ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="kNavigator">

<div class="home-page wrapper">
  <select multiple="multiple" class="search__box form-control" name="search__box">
  </select>
</div>

</ons-navigator>  
</script>
```

It's happening on both iOS and Android ..and even when testing it in the browser. I suspect that it might be due to the select2-container being generated outside of the home.html template ...but I've tried everything and I'm lost :(

Comment: It's better to close the `select2` on user scroll. So it will not make issues like this. actually, it's it defaults behaviour, I don't know why it's not triggering your app.! If you want I can help you with on scroll close `select2'.

Comment: @weBer I guess that would be a solution that results in at least a bit better experience. Do you have any snippet that can be used to close it on scroll?

Comment: give me 2 minutes I will make one for you.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to close the **`select2`** on user scroll. So it will not make issues like this. actually, it's **select2's defaults behaviou**r, I don't know why it's not triggering your app.! If you want I can help you with on scroll close `select2'.

**First Method**

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
   $("#select2-drop-mask").click();
});
```

**Second Method**

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
  ("#mySelectElement").select2("close");
});
```

**Third Method**

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
  $("#mySelectElement").select2().trigger("select2:close");
});
```

If you want you can also trigger this combining with `resize` function as a failsafe. Hope this helps you.

```
$(window).on('scroll resize', function(){
  $("#select2-drop-mask").click();
});
```